# From an apk file, can we delete an activity of an android application

Tags: android, apk

I want to make some changes on an android application based on its .apk file.

I could act on the XML part but I could not change all that is java code.

Is it possible to change the java code in the apk file and have another apk file ? If yes, how can i do it ?
Thank you for helping me.

Comment: This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6081365/9713349) might help.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome in stack overflow, Iskander Soltani!

First of all: **No, it isnt possible.** An apk file is signed and you cant get access to rebuild it.
If you want to change some code or xml layout files, you have to open the project with android studio or other IDE and edit your project not the apk file(!).

> An apk file is just the signed output of an android-project.

Did this asked your question?

Comment: thank you for your reply. In fact I do not have the source code of the application and I want to make some changes on the java code from the apk file. I found a solution we use the software apk studio, but I do not know if we can regenerate the apk file after the changes

Comment: I dont think so. There are ways to inspect apk files and extract them. On this way you could get some data. I mean if you could edit any apk file, you also could take the whatsapp.apk file and edit it to write more letters or some other features... This cant be legal and isnt possible. The only way to modify an apk file is using apps or software like lucky patcher, but its not sure that works.